# convert ObservableLis to ObservableValue

Tags: java, javafx

In my lambda expression it is necessary to use ObservableValue, but now I have ObservableList, I do not understand how to do it

I work with JavaFX and I need to infer the collection in a column in lambda expression

```java
private final ObservableList<String> nameLink = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public ObservableList<String> getNameLink() {
    return nameLink;
}

public ObservableList<String> setNameLink(String nameLink) {
    this.nameLink.add(nameLink);
    return getNameLink();
}
```

```java
contractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameLink());
```

Comment: `setNameLink(String nameLink)` indicates you always have only _one_ link. If that's true why do you have a list in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas there should be a list, it is necessary to alter

Comment: You could try using a `ListProperty<E>` which is an `ObservableListValue<E>` which is in turn an `ObservableValue<ObservableList<E>>`. However, your `setNameLink(String)` seems odd; why not just use `getNameLink().add(...)`?

Comment: I don't recommend give a method the name of a setter, if it's not actually a setter. You'd expect a setter to replace the property value without modifying it; your code `setNameLink` code fails to fulfill both expectations. A better name for the method would be `appendNameLink`. As for getting an `ObservableValue` out of an`ObservableList`:The best you can hope for is getting an`ObservableValue`for an element at a specific index.The`ObservableList`does not contain a single value to be observed,but some non-negative number of different values.You could wrap the list in a ObservableValue though.

Comment: @Slaw unfortunately it does not work

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @Slaw lambda expression error: `Bad return  type in lambda expression: ListProperty<String> cannot be converted to ObservableValue<String>`

Comment: See, this is where I was confused regarding your other question. You have a `TableColumn<..., String>` but your model class has an `ObservableList<String>`—this doesn't match at all. If each row in the column is supposed to contain a single "name link" then I don't understand the reason for using an `ObservableList`. If each row in the column is supposed to contain a _list_ of "name links", then your column should be declared as such (e.g. `TableColumn<..., ObservableList<String>>`). Or is your goal something else, like the cell should contain the last element or something...?

Comment: @Slaw yes it really helped - `private TableColumn<MainData, ObservableList<String>> contractColumn;` I would mark your answer as correct